# SQL order by datetime

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have 3 tables:

1. `chatmsgs` with the columns

   ```
   itemid, sender, receiver, message, datetime, status
   ```
2. `users` with the columns

   ```
   userid, username, phone, email, avatar, online, password
   ```
3. `items` with the columns

   ```
   itemid, category, make, type, mainimage, title, price
   ```

I am trying to create a list of chats between the current user and some other user on a specific item and order the list by the chat with the most recent message (based on `timestamp`).

My current query is this:

```
<?php
$currentuser=$_SESSION['userid'];
$sqls="SELECT DISTINCT itemid,sender,receiver FROM chatmsgs ORDER BY datetime DESC";
$results=mysqli_query($db,$sqls);
while($rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)){
    $itemid=$rows['itemid'];    $sender=$rows['sender'];    $receiver=$rows['receiver'];    #$message=$rows['message'];
    $sqll="SELECT * FROM items WHERE itemid = '".$itemid."'";
    $resultt=mysqli_query($db,$sqll);
    while($roww=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultt)){
        $itemid=$roww['itemid'];    $title=$roww['title'];  $status=$roww['status'];    $userid=$roww['userid'];
        #$sqlx = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid = '".$userid."' AND userid != '".$currentuser."'";
        $sqlx = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid = '".$userid."'";
        $resultx=mysqli_query($db,$sqlx);
        while($rowx=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultx)){
            $avatar=$rowx['avatar'];    $username=$rowx['username'];    $user=$rowx['userid'];
            $sq="SELECT * FROM chatmsgs WHERE itemid = '".$itemid."' AND ((sender = '".$sender."' AND receiver = '".$receiver."') OR (sender = '".$receiver."' AND receiver = '".$sender."')) ORDER BY id ASC";
            $resul=mysqli_query($db,$sq);
            while($ro=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resul)){
                $message=$ro['message'];
                $ldate=date_format(date_create($ro['datetime']),"M d");
            }   
            echo '
        <li>
       My list item
                </li>
            ';
        }
        
    }
}
```

?>

I  have so far been able to list the chats but I'm unable to sort it.

I know this is not the best way to do this but it's the only way I know how. Would appreciate better ways.

Comment: So, when there is a column "timestamp" within your table "chatmsgs", why don't you order by this column? Isn't that what you want to do?

Comment: @JonasMetzler sorry had made a mistake...in my code. The result I get doesn't order it the way I want

Comment: Four nested `while` loops, whoa. If you spell out the logic of how items should be fetched and refactor to match, and don't use `while` when you're only fetching one row, I imagine you can dramatically simplify your code.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by getting all chat messages associated with just the given user in question.  By doing a UNION as both the sender and receiver, if you have an index on each column respectively, the query should be very fast. From that, you can now query the rest of the data all in one quick run something like below.

You can order the data by whatever... From your while loops, it looked like you were doing all things for a given Item ID before moving to the next, so I have the order by clause by the item ID.  Now, from within each item, I have ordered by the date/time in descending order with newest chat message first, but you could change that.

Another possible change is you may want the items displayed based on which is the MOST RECENT item that has chat activity first.  For example, if a chat from someone was from a year ago, vs one that was just this week, you might want the current first.  I would alter the query slightly.

```
select
        um.itemid,
        cm.message,
        cm.datetime,
        cm.status,
        uFrom.username senderName,
        uFrom.avatar senderAvatar,
        uTo.userName receiptName,
        uTo.avatar receiptAvatar,
        i.category,
        i.make,
        i.type,
        i.mainImage,
        i.title,
        i.price
    from
        ( select distinct itemid
                from chatMsgs 
                where sender = $currentuser
            UNION
            select distinct itemid
                from chatMsgs 
                where receiver = $currentuser ) UM
            JOIN ChatMsgs ch
                on UM.ItemID = ch.ItemID
                JOIN Users uFrom
                    on ch.sender = uFrom.userid
                JOIN Users uTo
                    on ch.receiver = uTo.userid
                JOIN Items i
                    on ch.itemID = i.itemid
    order by
        um.itemid,
        cm.datetime desc
```

The format is not in php format, but you can see the only place you need a parameter is where the user ID is.  All the details come along in the results including the respective avatars, titles, messages, from user and recipient user too.  Take what you need in one query.

I would expect two individual indexes on your chatmsgs table.  One on the sender, one on the receiver.

Comment: Unfortunately this query will list all the messages. However, the query I need has to kind of like group them in such a way that on one list-item I have a conversation between two users about one particular  item and the most recent conversation to end is displayed first.

Comment: @EllyNw, dont over think that.  What I have is the everything joining user to / from.  If you are looking for a SPECIFIC user, or for a specific list item, just add that to the respective table source with an "AND" clause within the select/union segment